# Can compilers actually recognize time complexity improvements and implement them behind the scenes?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I remember reading a post here about just how good modern compilers are. The example provided in that post cited an example program similar to this:

```
int sumOfIntegers(int n) {
    return n == 1 ? 1 : n + sumOfIntegers(n-1);
}
```

They alleged that this could be optimized by a modern compiler. Written as is, the above function has a runtime of O(n), but this person claimed a good compiler these days would turn this into a constant time operation, recognizing that the sum of integers could be performed by Gauss's formula [image] and would implement this function like so behind the scenes.

I have been playing around with the compiler explorer at https://godbolt.org/, but have been unable to generate assembly that would imply this in C++. Is something like this truly possible? I cannot find the original post, and while plausible, it almost sounds too good to be true.

Comment: Which compiler(s) did you try and which optimization level? When I try with the latest clang and `-O2`, I get generated code without loops for [all three versions I tried](https://godbolt.org/z/z3PKehEj7).

Comment: @sepp2k It was the `-O2` I was missing. Once I include that I see the same things as you. Thank you!